# reading only 12-bits from SPI on MSP430F2122, is it possible?

Tags: spi, msp430

I'm trying to read data from a RGB sensor (S9706) and I thought about using the SPI for the readings.

The problem is that the sensor wants a little pause of 3-4us after each 12-bits (the colors resolution is 12-bit) I read,
and the hardware SPI can read 7 or 8 bits at once.
So if I choose to read 7-bits each time, I will not be able to make the pause after 12-bits, and I might loose some data while reading 2 more bits than I should.

[image: S9706 Timing chart]

Is there a way to read exactly 12-bits (12 clock pulses only) with the SPI, or should I write a bit-bangging function to do what I want?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Eventually, I choose to do it with bit banging, although I think it might be possible to use SPI with low a frequency of 200Khz.
With 200Khz every clock will be 10us, 50% dc = 5us, and it's more than the pause I need after every 12 bits.

what I don't sure is what will happen between bit 37 to 40, because the SPI will read 5 bytes (40 bits) and the sensor has data for 36 bits. It might start sending new data from the next 36 bits..

Comment: You can't transmit only 12-bits over SPI. Has to be bytes. Since you only need one way communication, bit banging seems easiest.

Comment: @Josiah Hester Thank you. that's what I did eventually

Comment: Actually, there are microcontrollers out there that support a variable transfer length of 8 to 16 bits. See for example NXP's LPC21xx series. So stating that SPI is always a multiple of 8 bits/byte-wise is misleading at best.

Comment: @FRob you are right, since SPI is not formally standardized that is the case. But 8-bit SPI is common on MSP430 devices, that was what I meant.

Comment: On this specific family it can be either 7 or 8.

Comment: @JosiahHester Heh! SPI isn't formally standardized at all - it's a de-facto standard.